# How to read TaskScheduler logs in from Windows Server "application and services logs" in Python

Tags: python, windows, events, logging

How can I read (in Python) the logs from Windows Server 2008:

```
    Event Viewer
      Application and Services Logs
         Microsoft
            Windows
               Task Scheduler
                  Operational
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you would do it with Python without tapping out to some sort of C/C++ support?

But, then I thought, maybe you could shell from python, and use [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659)?  Logparser can return nicely formatted output you could easily shred in python.  However, if LogParser supports searching the extended log files, I couldn't get it to work on my Windows Server 2008 R2 server.

But, then I thought, well, you could maybe tap out to PowerShell, surely?  However, not using the `get-eventlog` cmdlet like I had thought would be the answer.

Ultimately, I was able to query the event records of the log file "Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational", but I had to tap out to C# to do it from PowerShell.

To sum up this sad story:

- use whatever C/C++ extension support python has built in to call new [Windows Event Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385772%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions
- use custom .net ([EventLogQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogquery.aspx)/[EventLogReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogreader.aspx)) code to ETL from event log format into something python can natively consume

See [Event Queries and Event Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399427.aspx) for samples on how to construct the query.

Comment: Thanks, Zach. Python has the pywin32 library with support for API such as  win32evtlog.ReadEventLog. Is that what you meant ?

Comment: I tried to use it, but it was not clear to me hot to get to the specific branch of the tree as shown above.

Comment: Not win32evtlog.ReadEventLog unless it supports the new extended log files - which I'm not sure it would if MS own PowerShell doesn't. Plus you not being able to 'get to the specific branch' also makes me think its not supported. I was actually assuming python has some way you could write an extension in C/C++ and call it from python?  If it does, you could try those Windows Event Log functions.  They are the  new ones that support extended log files.

Comment: I suppose it does not support the extended log. So, it seems that pure Python is stuck here. I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe someone with a little more foo will come along and provide some more insight.  Good luck!

Comment: I am as well interested in a solution. Trying to open one of the logs results in an opened "Application" log.

Comment: Here is some more info: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/882df3d5-9a9b-437b-a6ab-e09873ce6ece/cant-access-event-log-for-tasks?forum=csharplanguage